# Html video controll doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video

I'm trying to display a video on my website. Here is the code:

```
<video controls>
  <source src="my_location.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="my_location.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
  <source src="my_location.webm" type="video/webm" />
  Your browser does not support this content
</video>
```

It worked for all browser but the problem is that the pause button on Firefox does not work event if I have the controls attribute on my video and ogv format.

Does someone know why ?

Comment: FireFox is the new IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dedicated pause button - instead the play button is toggled with a pause button after it's clicked. See also the example at w3schools.com:

http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_video.asp

ADDITION:

This in your code:

`<source src="my_location.ogv" type="video/ogv"   />`

should be

`<source src="my_location.ogv" type="video/ogg"   />` .

(`ogg` instead of `ogv` on the file type / not on the file extension itself).