# :hover on img in firefox does't work

Tags: html, css, firefox, hover

I,m trying to increase the width (scale) of the image of a button with :hover but it doesn't work on firefox (but it works on all others browsers).

HTML:

```
<div class="my_class">
    <button><img src="my_location.png" ></button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.my_class button img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
```

}

Do you see something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale function takes two values, one for x and one for y. if you want to transform a single axis, only one argument is needed.

```
transform: scale(2, 0.5);
transform: scaleX(2);
transform: scaleY(0.5);
```

**Update**

Move the `:hover` to the `button`. Also, you should put the un-prefixed property after the prefixed ones.

```css
div.my_class button:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);  
}
```

```html
<div class="my_class">
  <button><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Britskorthaar-64091287828362D7bA.jpg/220px-Britskorthaar-64091287828362D7bA.jpg" ></button>
</div
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but it did'nt work. my transform works on chrome and safari (didn't test the rest)

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Tested in Firefox/Chrome/etc. and it's working well.

Comment: Any time (literally).

Comment: You seems to have experience with firefox please if you got time check my other post on pause button that doesn't work on firefox : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094648/html-video-controll-doesnt-work-on-firefox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111327/discussion-between-anonym-and-andy-hoffman).